What are the different ways that biomass emissions are measured / accounted?
The Guardian says that Ember reports that the DRAX wood pellet biomass power station produced nearly 3% of the UK’s total carbon emissions.  These claims are countered by the company and government by questioning the methodology:

A spokesperson for the company dismissed the thinktank’s findings as “flawed” and accused its authors of ignoring its “widely accepted and internationally recognised approach to carbon accounting”.


A government spokesperson said the report “fundamentally misrepresents” how biomass emissions are measured.

The most recent report relating to DRAX on the Ember Website Search is from April and just reports on DRAX's annual report.
What are these different ways of accounting for carbon emissions?

It's not flawed. Biomass releases CO2, and it's dirtier than coal. In this Q/A pair, I show that burning coal makes more sense than burning wood.
The incorrect theory is that since biomass has captured carbon dioxide from the atmosphere into carbon in the biomass, that burning it would somehow be "free", since it would only release that carbon back to the atmosphere which was captured. The theory further says that the carbon would be released anyway. This claim that the carbon would be released anyway is false, since you can make long-lived products out of biomass. Wood can be used to make furniture and wooden houses, where it retains the carbon dioxide for at least 100 years, maybe even more if we stop burning recycled wood. More importantly, biomass can be used to make biochar which retains the carbon practically forever, in a product that does not decompose. If you burn that wood, it releases the carbon immediately. It's true that not all wood is sawlogs, so some other use has to be had for the rest that's not suitable for sawmills, but that other use could very well be making biochar instead of burning it.
So the only way biomass can be burned for "free" is if you capture the carbon dioxide (which means it must be a large immobile point source, not for example a fireplace of an individual building or a motor vehicle), and either store the carbon dioxide permanently somewhere or make something out of it which can be stored easily, like making liquid oil products for example, which could be pumped back to exhausted oil wells (but which could be burned in motor vehicles as well, but this would be counterproductive in this day and age of electric vehicles).
Since typical biomass power plants do not have carbon capture, they can't be claimed to be free of CO2 emissions.
